# Dynatable.js sort german date

Tags: dynatable

I use php and dynatable.js (version 0.3.1) to create dynamic tables with a sort and search function. This setup works very well even with the U.S. formatted date from the SQL database. But I need the german date format in the table (`dd.mm.yy` or `dd.mm.yyyy`) to sort the entries.

I can't find a solution for my problem in the documentation from dynatable.js. Has someone had a similar problem with the date format in dynatable and maybe a hack or other kind of solution?

Comment: Note Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. We expect you to write some code first.

Comment: I have a working version from dynatable.js/php from mysql. The problem is only that dynatable.js can only sort us date and not other types like german date. I have found examples with jquery but iam looking for a solution with Dynatable.